# knitr::is_word_output() to check if the current output type is word – just like knitr::is_latex_output() and knitr::is_html_output()

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, pandoc

`knitr::is_latex_output()` and `knitr::is_html_output()` allow checking if the current output type [LaTex or HTML respectively](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-html.html).

Is there an equivalent for Word as an output format?

If not, what would be the most simple to use workaround?

````
---
title: "MWE for different file formats in namespace:knitr"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r}
if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
  cat("HTML") 
  }
if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
  cat("LATEX") 
  }
if (knitr::is_word_output()) {
  cat("WORD")
}
## Error: 'is_word_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'
```
````

Comment: Take a look at the functions. Maybe you can do something with knitr:::pandoc_to()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [knitr 1.31](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/tag/v1.31) (released in January 2021), you can use [`knitr::pandoc_to()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/knitr/man/output_type.html) in either of the following ways:

````
```{r}
if (knitr::pandoc_to("docx")) {
  cat("Word") 
}
```

```{r, include=knitr::pandoc_to("docx")}
cat("Word")
```
````

To conditionally output literal text content (rather than R code), it's easiest to use an [`asis` chunk](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/eng-asis.html) (note that we need to use the `echo` option instead of `include`):

````
```{asis, echo=knitr::pandoc_to("docx")}
This will only appear in Word documents.
```

```{asis, echo=knitr::pandoc_to("docx", "pdf")}
This will be appear in Word and PDF documents.
```
````

### Historical answer

In earlier versions of knitr, you can use an internal knitr function to get the type you want:

```
is_word_output <- function(fmt = knitr:::pandoc_to()) {
  length(fmt) == 1 && fmt == "docx"
}
```