# How can I switch R code inside R code block of RMarkdown depending on Knit output, HTML or Word?

Tags: r, knitr

I want to use different R codes when I do `Knit to HTML` or `Knit to Word`.
What I want to do is to use `kableExtra` when `Knit to HTML`, but to use `flextable` to output table when `Knit to Word`.
How can I switch depending on output format?

When `Knit to HTML`, do like:

```
#flextable(df) %>% 
#  theme_zebra() %>% 
#  width(width = 1.2) 

df %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_paper(c("striped"), full_width = F)
# I prefer this output style.
```

When `Knit to Word`, do like:

```
flextable(df) %>% 
  theme_zebra() %>% 
  width(width = 1.2) 

#df %>%
#  kbl() %>%
#  kable_paper(c("striped"), full_width = F)
# Unfortunately, with `Knit to Word`, this fails.
```

I want to switch, because `df %>% kbl() %>% kable_paper(c("striped"), full_width = F)` fails as below when `Knit to Word`, so alternatively I have to use `flextable(df) %>% theme_zebra() %>% width(width = 1.2)` for `Knit to Word`.

```
processing file: test.Rmd
                                                                                                                      
output file: test.knit.md

Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML.
If your aiming to have some HTML widgets shown in non-HTML format as a screenshot,
please install webshot or webshot2 R package for knitr to do the screenshot.
Alternatively, you can allow HTML output in non-HTML formats
by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: true

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.

Execution halted
```

Thanks in advance.

I want to enable somehow like below.

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
   word_document:
   html_document:
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r load libraries, include = FALSE, comment = "", eval = TRUE}
library(knitr)
```
```{r load libraries additional, include = FALSE, comment = "", eval = TRUE}
packages <- c(
  'kableExtra', 
  'magrittr',
  'flextable'
)
for (package in packages){
  library(package, character.only = T)
}
```


## Test


```{r echo = F, results='asis'}
content_df <- "a,b,c
1,5,6
2,2,2"

df <- read.table(textConnection(content_df), sep = ",", header = T)
df0 <- read.table(textConnection(content_df), sep = ",", header = F)
colnames(df) <- df0[1,]

if (is_knitr_to_word){
  flextable(df) %>% 
    theme_zebra() %>% 
    width(width = 1.2) 
} else {
  df %>%
    kbl() %>%
    kable_paper(c("striped"), full_width = F)
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer that addresses this on the [Posit Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/conditionaly-run-a-chunk-depends-on-an-output-format/55685) by user joels.  The gist is that you can use `is_html_output()` either as the `eval` argument of a chunk to turn it on or off as you change the output format or within a chunk with an `if else` statement to change the output within a chunk that will always be evaluated.  Here's the answer from the Posit post:

> You can do this with the function is_html_output() from the knitr package. There is also is_latex_output() if you want to allow for that option as well.
>
> ```
> library(knitr)
>
> if(is_html_output()) {
>   kable(cars)
> } else {
>   cars
> }
> ```
>
> If you want chunk evaluation to depend on document type, you could do:
>
> ```
> kable(cars)
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the nice suggestion of key word (function) of `is_html_output()` and `is_latex_output()`!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comment of DaveArmstrong telling `is_html_output()` and `is_latex_output()`, after noticing there is no `is_word_output()` or `is_docx_output()`, I found the answer of this post by users Florian and igelstorm:
[knitr::is_word_output() to check if the current output type is word – just like knitr::is_latex_output() and knitr::is_html_output()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389948/knitris-word-output-to-check-if-the-current-output-type-is-word-just-like)

> As of knitr 1.31 (released in January 2021), you can use knitr::pandoc_to() in either of the following ways:
>
> ````
> ```{r}
> if (knitr::pandoc_to("docx")) {
>   cat("Word") 
> }
> ```
> ````
>
> ````
> ```{r, include=knitr::pandoc_to("docx")}
> cat("Word")
> ```
> ````

So I solved as follows, to make default as `kbl`, say, for html, pdf, etc., and use `flextable` only for word:

```
if (knitr::pandoc_to("docx")) {
  flextable(df) %>% 
    theme_zebra() %>% 
    width(width = 1.2) 
} else {
  df %>%
    kbl() %>%
    kable_paper(c("striped"), full_width = F)
}
```