# test if rmarkdown format is rdocx_document similar to knitr::is_html_output()

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, officer

Depending on format output, I want all plots in `rmarkdown` to be a certain size if the output is `word` (`officedown::rdocx_document:`) and a different size if the output is `html` (`bookdown::html_document2:`).

I was thinking this could be achieved by having two chunks at the start where only one is evaluated if the output is the one I want, something like this `test.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "test"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
always_allow_html: true 
---


```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r htmltest, include = FALSE, eval = knitr::is_html_output()}
#if output if html, run this:
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.width = 10, fig.height = 8)
```


```{r wordtest, include = FALSE, eval = knitr::is_latex_output()}
#if output if rdocx_document, run this:
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.width = 5, fig.height = 5)
```


# plot1

```{r plot, include = TRUE, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE}

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line()

```

# plot2 
```{r plot2, include = TRUE, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE}

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line()

```

# end
````

For the case of the `html`, the following `render` call works:

```
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_format = "html_document2")
```

but for the `officedown::rdocx_document:` call, it doesn't work:

```
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_format = "rdocx_document")
```

This is to be expected as I test for `knitr::is_latex_output()` in the code.

What is the equivalent of `knitr::is_latex_output()` or `knitr::is_html_output()` for `officedown::rdocx_document:`?

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389948/knitris-word-output-to-check-if-the-current-output-type-is-word-just-like) mentions that for `word`, you can run `include=knitr::pandoc_to("docx")` but I have tried that and it didn't work (I think its because its for standard `word` output `word_document:` and not `officedown::rdocx_document:`)

Any suggestions (or comments on the approach I'm taking)?

thanks

**edit**

When I run and render using the following as @stefan suggested:

````
```{r wordtest, include = FALSE, eval = knitr::pandoc_to("docx")}
#if output if rdocx_document, run this:
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.width = 5, fig.height = 5)
```
````

I get the following `Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1`. I don't get this when I render the `html` format.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lubridate_1.9.2  forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.0    dplyr_1.1.2      purrr_1.0.1      readr_2.1.4      tidyr_1.3.0      tibble_3.2.1     ggplot2_3.4.2    tidyverse_2.0.0  officer_0.6.3    flextable_0.9.4  officedown_0.3.1 bookdown_0.37    rmarkdown_2.25 


pandoc_version()
[1] ‘3.1.1’
```

Comment: Hm.  Using`eval = knitr::pandoc_to("docx")` works fine for me.

Comment: @stefan that doesnt work for me, I have included some `sessionInfo` and more details above. Do you see any differences with the package versions you are using or `pandoc_version` above?

Comment: @stefan of course I had left a previous word document open with the same name so it couldn't overwrite it, problem solved, thanks for your comment!